# Some values in fields change while creating dictionary from data read in Pandas

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a tsv (tab separated) file with data like this:

```
1 102 blue   url description1 somethingelse1
2 102 brown  url description2 somethingelse2
3 102 purple url description3 somethingelse3
4 102 tan    url description4 somethingelse4
5 102 white  url description5 somethingelse5
```

This is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('sample_match.tsv', error_bad_lines=False, sep='\t', header=None, names=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'])

df = df[df.C.notnull()]
df = df[df.C != 'Multi']
df = df[df.C != 'Natural']
gb = df.groupby('B')
groups = dict(list(gb)) # Create dictionary
print groups
```

And, I noticed that wherever there was `tan` in the field `C`, it got replaced by `brown`, other fields staying unchanged. Why does it happen and how to fix it? I'm using Pandas version 0.15.2.

My output looks like this:

```
{102: A B C D\
1 102 blue   url  
2 102 brown  url  
3 102 purple url  
4 102 brown  url  
5 102 white  url

    E \
description...
description...
description...
description...
description...

     F
somethingel...
somethingel...
somethingel...
somethingel...
somethingel... }
```

Comment: Can you add your output? Is impossible upgrade `pandas`?

Comment: Could you paste the original data as you have? I believe you have problems with the characters in your tsv file. Perform sanity checks and print the dataframe after each step to confirm, please.

Comment: @jezrael Posted my output

Comment: It looks like bug, in my pandas version `0.18.1` it works very nice. `{102:    A    B       C    D             E               F
0  1  102    blue  url  description1  somethingelse1
1  2  102   brown  url  description2  somethingelse2
2  3  102  purple  url  description3  somethingelse3
3  4  102     tan  url  description3  somethingelse4
4  5  102   white  url  description5  somethingelse5}`. Please upgrade pandas.